# You can’t apply induction to reason about uncountable sets, can you?

Tags: soft-question, induction

My question is a soft one.
Induction as a proof technique I admire, but to my knowledge it is strongly coupled with the “least element principle” and enumerability (labeling something uniquely with natural numbers).

That’s how I deduce that one can’t use induction to reason about cardinalities bigger then the set of natural numbers, for example set of real numbers.

Am I right?
Are there generalizations to the non-enumerable case?

Comment: There is something called [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) that you can check out.

Comment: Aside from transfinite induction, there are ways to use traditional induction to reason about the real numbers. For example, if $P(x)$ is a statement about real numbers, you can’t use induction directly to prove $\forall x\in\mathbb R^{\geq0},P(x)$ but you can prove $Q(n)$ by induction:$$\forall x\in\mathbb R(n\leq x<n+1 \implies P(x))$$ which then proves $\forall x\in\mathbb R^{\geq 0}:P(x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) is the first thing to read up on.

In a nutshell it uses the induction you're used to to climb up through successor ordinals, but then there is a new sort of case you have to deal with in your inductive process: what to do when you hit a **limit ordinal**.

So it is not much different. Your proposed induction needs to establish a base case, successor case, and limit case, and then it works the same way.

An example of something defined this way is the Krull-Gabriel-Rentschler dimension of a module.  It is used to assign a dimension to a module even when its lattice of submodules has uncountably long chains.

Regular recursion is, of course, not concerned with the limit case, because you only care about all the successors leading up to the first limit ordinal ($\omega$.)